# Should I Use Oauth 2.0 for SAAS Sign In

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, express, oauth

I am trying to learn and implement MEAN stack (node, express, mongo, angular) to create an SAAS application I have been working on.

Currently i'm working on the REST API that the frontend will consume. I am having trouble understanding / deciding on an authentication scheme.

I am looking into passport.js to use with the REST API but I feel like maybe i'm confused about its implementation. Everything I read about oauth 2.0 says its pretty much the defacto standard for authentication with modern REST api's however most of what i'm reading says you click a button and it asks for authorization, just like a facebook or twitter signon.

So i'm wondering, is it even necessary to have a token based authentication if I just want my users to provide an email and password and sign in.

Can someone explain this at least: If I use Oauth 2.0, do I have to have sign in buttons that initiate some kind of facebook connect looking flow, or can I have a user provide an email and password and use that as a means to obtain the tokens from the oauth server.

SO CONFUSED. haha. I just need to figure out a good, acceptable way besides plain old username / password authentication to secure the api so I can get on with the build. All suggestions and links to applicable tutorials are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have much to offer for this except that the Auth in OAuth is supposed to be Authorization. It is possible to use OAuth for authentication, but I think that is generally not encouraged. Here is some more info on why it's problematic: http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html?m=1

Comment: So if i'm doing a web application and i'm not having any 3rd parties connecting to this api, I should be fine to just use the standard passport.js simple authentication?

Comment: Yes. OAuth is great for accessing resources on Facebook without users having to give their Facebook login credentials to lots of applications, for example. If you aren't going to have third party apps integrate with you (and therefore you don't have to worry about users sharing their credentials with third parties) you probably don't really need OAuth. (Just my two cents, I'm not much of an expert on this topic).

Comment: have a look at my reply to your other question, I think it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636514/1204329